# How to select records for the Current Month In Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle11g

I am writing a Java Program where I am required to select Records for the Current Month from an Oracle database. Any time I need to select Records for the Current day I use:

```
select * from purchases where purchase_date = to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

What Method should I use to select records from the current Month?
On the table the dates appear like:

```
10/4/2012 //for 4th October 2012
```

I tried

```
select * from purchases where purchase_date like to_char(sysdate, 'MON-YYYY')
```

This selects nothing of course please assist.

Comment: What you have tried ? Add relevant code here.

Comment: Why not determine the first and last day of given month, and select all purchases with *puchase_date* between those two dates?

Comment: What is `purchase_date`, what type? Whatever you are doing with `sysdate` try doing the same with the `purchase_date` and then compare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `purchase_date` is a DATE.

```
select * 
from 
   purchases 
where 
   purchase_date >= trunc(sysdate,'mm')
```

If `purchase_date` is a VARCHAR

```
select * 
from 
   purchases 
where 
   to_date(purchase_date,'mm/dd/yyyy') >= trunc(sysdate,'mm')
```

trunc(sysdate,'mm') truncates the current date keeping the month and obviously the year, so `10/04/2012 08:58` is truncated to `10/01/2012 00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming purchase_date is a `VARCHAR2` and formatted like `DD-MON-YYYY`, which appears to be the case, then:

```
select * from purchases where trunc(to_date(purchase_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'MONTH') = trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')
```